# Trouble with tab delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

first time on stack overflow

I'm trying to import a text file into pandas.read_csv, but the delimiter doesn't seem to like '\t'. Rather than showing up as 250 or so columns the output shows as 1 single column. I tried

```
sep = '\\\\t'
```

as well but to no avail.

the output looks like this
[image: the output looks like this]
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It should just be `sep = '\t'`. Why are you adding additional escapes?

Comment: Using just the one escape gave the same result. I saw on another question here about using multiple escapes.

Comment: Can you link to an example file (could be just the first few lines of your file) that reproduces this error? Also, it seems like the first lines in your file are metadata and not formatted properly to be read in as rows, but you aren't skipping them when you call `.read_csv`. I don't know if this is what causes your problem or if that's another issue.

Comment: Sure, but I won’t be able to provide an example file until Monday

Comment: Can we try `sep='\\t'`

Comment: That gives me this message:

     Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 250. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.